# Binding a list of objects to a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have this piece of code:

```
public class Member
    {
        public string name;
        public string id;
        public int days;
        public string check;

    }

private void Function(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ValidateInput())
        {
            List<Member> Members = new List<Member>();
            API.Authenticate(key,id);
            Members = API.Method1();

            Members = API.Method2(Members);

            foreach(Member item in Members)
            {
                Results.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
    }
```

and I'm adding them to a listView that have a DisplayMemberBinding for certain fields of the class.

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
         <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" Width="150"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" Width="130"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Check" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding check}" Width="220"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Days" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding days}" Width="120"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

And after the procedure is done I have a list view that's populated, but all columns are completely blank and I can't see where the problem is.
I've tried to check the data but everything was OK.

What am I doing wrong here? and of course, names were changed to cover up the real goal of the application as it's a bit of a tricky project.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the problem.
The issue is that elements that are binded with DisplayMemberBinding have to be properties and not fields.

```
public class Member
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int days { get; set; }
    public string check { get; set; }
}
```

This fixed the problem!